# snakeyaml dump empty field instead of null

Tags: null, yaml, snakeyaml

I have a LinkedHashMap where some values might be null and I want them to be dumped as empty fields instead of null. Is it even possible or am I wrecking my nerves in vain? Also how can I get rid of the single quotes in case there is an integer printed?

My code:

```java
Map<String, Object> map = org.createOrgYamlMap();
    DumperOptions options= new DumperOptions();
    options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
    options.setPrettyFlow(true);
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(orgDirectory.toString() + "/organization.yml"));
    yaml.dump(map, writer);
```

Gives me the yaml file:

```
uuid: '123'
name: test1
document_vault: null
```

What I want:

```
uuid: 123
name: test1
document_vault:
```

Answer (score 3):

Override representMapping method of Representer class.

```
Map<String, Object> map = org.createOrgYamlMap();

Representer representer = new Representer() {
        @Override
        protected Node representMapping(Tag tag, Map<?, ?> mapping, Boolean flowStyle) {
            List<NodeTuple> value = new ArrayList<NodeTuple>(mapping.size());
            MappingNode node = new MappingNode(tag, value, flowStyle);
            representedObjects.put(objectToRepresent, node);
            boolean bestStyle = true;
            for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : mapping.entrySet()) {
                Node nodeKey = representData(entry.getKey());
                //If value is null then treat it as empty string.
                Node nodeValue = entry.getValue() == null ?
                        representData("") : representData(entry.getValue());
                if (!(nodeKey instanceof ScalarNode && ((ScalarNode) nodeKey).getStyle() == null)) {
                    bestStyle = false;
                }
                if (!(nodeValue instanceof ScalarNode && ((ScalarNode) nodeValue).getStyle() == null)) {
                    bestStyle = false;
                }
                value.add(new NodeTuple(nodeKey, nodeValue));
            }
            if (flowStyle == null) {
                if (defaultFlowStyle != FlowStyle.AUTO) {
                    node.setFlowStyle(defaultFlowStyle.getStyleBoolean());
                } else {
                    node.setFlowStyle(bestStyle);
                }
            }
            return node;
        }
    };


DumperOptions options= new DumperOptions();
options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
options.setPrettyFlow(true);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer, options);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(orgDirectory.toString() + "/organization.yml"));
yaml.dump(map, writer);
```

**Test code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Map<String, Object> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    lhm.put("c", null);

    DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
    Representer representer = new Representer() {
        @Override
        protected Node representMapping(Tag tag, Map<?, ?> mapping, Boolean flowStyle) {
            List<NodeTuple> value = new ArrayList<NodeTuple>(mapping.size());
            MappingNode node = new MappingNode(tag, value, flowStyle);
            representedObjects.put(objectToRepresent, node);
            boolean bestStyle = true;
            for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : mapping.entrySet()) {
                Node nodeKey = representData(entry.getKey());
                Node nodeValue = entry.getValue() == null ?
                        representData("") : representData(entry.getValue());
                if (!(nodeKey instanceof ScalarNode && ((ScalarNode) nodeKey).getStyle() == null)) {
                    bestStyle = false;
                }
                if (!(nodeValue instanceof ScalarNode && ((ScalarNode) nodeValue).getStyle() == null)) {
                    bestStyle = false;
                }
                value.add(new NodeTuple(nodeKey, nodeValue));
            }
            if (flowStyle == null) {
                if (defaultFlowStyle != FlowStyle.AUTO) {
                    node.setFlowStyle(defaultFlowStyle.getStyleBoolean());
                } else {
                    node.setFlowStyle(bestStyle);
                }
            }
            return node;
        }
    };

    options.setDefaultFlowStyle(FlowStyle.BLOCK);

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer, options);
    String s = yaml.dump(lhm);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output:**

```
c: ''
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
It's just that people that aren't too coding aware are supposed to be using this file. So just an empty field would be more elegant, and there are other values that aren't  Strings as well, so having single quotes might be confusing. Don't know if that's possible but I would suppose so, as reading an empty field sure is.

Comment: You can extend SafeRepresenter or Representer.  Override the inner class `RepresentNull` to be an empty string.  https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/src/f75151daf2b18b68205010587fdbec8889b5ede8/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/SafeRepresenter.java#lines-102

Answer (score 2):

Just debated myself with this same question where I wanted null to be printed as `~` instead of `null`.

As per their [tests](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/187d7e47d1e91777238602470ea3f0ce2d480636/src/test/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/types/NullTagTest.java#lines-115), you can easily achive by

```java
    public void test() {
        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        options.setDefaultFlowStyle(FlowStyle.BLOCK);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new NullRepresenter(), options);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("uuid", "123");
        map.put("document_vault", null);
        String output = yaml.dump(map);
        assertEquals("uuid: 123\ndocument_vault: ~\n", output);
    }

    private class NullRepresenter extends Representer {
        public NullRepresenter() {
            super();
            // null representer is exceptional and it is stored as an instance variable.
            this.nullRepresenter = new RepresentNull();
        }

        private class RepresentNull implements Represent {
            public Node representData(Object data) {
                return representScalar(Tag.NULL, "~");
            }
        }
    }
```

Since `''` is not part of the [allowed values](http://yaml.org/type/null.html) it will be prepended the null tag.

```
document_vault: !!null ''
```